# Web Scraping a Table which extends to "Next" page (without change in url) in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the table from [this](https://agmarknet.gov.in/SearchCmmMkt.aspx?Tx_Commodity=24&Tx_State=0&Tx_District=0&Tx_Market=0&DateFrom=06-May-2020&DateTo=06-May-2020&Fr_Date=06-May-2020&To_Date=06-May-2020&Tx_Trend=0&Tx_CommodityHead=Potato&Tx_StateHead=--Select--&Tx_DistrictHead=--Select--&Tx_MarketHead=--Select--) page. The table has some 400 rows of which only 50 are displayed at a time.

The source code of the page shows only the **first** 50 items even if I open the source code when later items are displayed (after clicking next). Snippet of the source code is below:

```
                                                50
                                        </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_Labdistrict_name_49">Bangalore</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_LabdMarketName_49">Bangalore</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_Labcomm_name_49">Potato</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_LabdVariety_49">Local</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_LabdVariety_49">FAQ</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_LabMinPrice_49">1800</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_Labmaxpric_49">1900</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_LabModalpric_49">1850</span>
                            </td><td>
                                <span id="cphBody_GridPriceData_LabReportedDate_49">06 May 2020</span>
                            </td>
            </tr><tr align="left">
                <td colspan="10"><table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="image" src="../images/Next.png" alt=">" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphBody$GridPriceData&#39;,&#39;Page$Next&#39;);return false;" /></td><td><input type="image" src="../images/Last.png" alt=" >>" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphBody$GridPriceData&#39;,&#39;Page$Last&#39;);return false;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I don't know Java but from web found that V8 package in R can be used for Java rendered content on web pages. In the code above, I think the `onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphBody$GridPriceData&#39;,&#39;Page$Next&#39;);return false;` is the part from where the next part of the table can be accessed. The `__doPostBack` function is defined above in the source code of the page.

I scraped the table till row 50 and extract the function code using `html_nodes("script")`. But couldn't get the call part of the function.

How do I get the data from next pages?

Apologies for the long post.

Comment: If you need to click on the "next" button for js to render etc. Have a look at [`RSelenium`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html). If the button "just" redirects to the next page (different, constructable url), just use [`rvest`](https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest).

Comment: @David it is not redirecting to a next page as the url doesn't change. Will have a look at RSelenium. Can V8 not be used?

Comment: To my understanding (haven't worked with V8 so far), V8 is for generating websites etc. RSelenium et al are used to access websites "like a real user".

Comment: @David So i browsed on how to get this done with RSelenium. As u mentioned, I think i can use it to click on the next button using it but since the webpage is not changing the html source code still doesn't have the remaining part of the table. Couldn't find how to deal with that. Can you guide me to good source or answer the question above?